# Angular, test which component is instantiate when navigate with router

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular5

I'd like to know if there is a way to test which component is instantiate when navigating to a route.

I have this route :

```
const routes: Routes = [{path: ':anyString', component: AnyStringComponent}];
```

I want to test with unit-test :

```
router.navigate(['azdfz4896']);
// expect instantiated component to be AnyStringComponent
```

Is there a way to test that ?

Comment: Did you try enabling router tracing? If yes, isn't that enough ?

Comment: I was more thinking about unit-testing than debug tracing

Answer (score 1):

you can mock [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)  and try :

```
route.snapshot._routeConfig.component.name
```

to get the component name from [snapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot)

ActivatedRoute mock:

```
export class MockActivatedRoute implements ActivatedRoute{
 component : Type<any>|string;
 snapshot : ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
 url : Observable<UrlSegment[]>;
 params : Observable<Params>;
 queryParams : Observable<Params>;
 data : Observable<Data>;
 outlet : string;
 ...  
}

...
```

your test

```
router = TestBed.get(Router);
location = TestBed.get(Location);
router.initialNavigation();
....
it('navigate to "search" takes you to /search', fakeAsync(() => {
  route = new MockActivatedRoute();
  router.navigate(['azdfz4896']);
  tick();
  expect(location.path()).toBe('/azdfz4896');
  expect(route.snapshot.component.name).toBe('AnyStringComponent');
}));
```

wish that will help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try it when i'll have time and i'll give you feedback