# How to mock ActivatedRoute from Angular 5 tests - error Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-test

This is my constructor with ActivatedRoute

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.claimId = +route.snapshot.params["claimId"];
  }
```

And I'm trying to mock this ActivateRoute in tests in that way:

```
beforeEach((() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TransactionSummaryComponent],
      providers: [{
        provide: useClass: MockClaim
      }, {
        provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
          params: Observable.of({ claimId: 1 })
        }
      }]
    });
```

But whilst building tests I receiving an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`

Comment: check this bro https://stackoverflow.com/a/50152600/4399281

Answer (score 2):

I have changed they way of getting id:

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.claimId = +params["claimId"];
    });
 }
```

And it works now.